# Checking tree node equal to a value

Tags: c++, recursion, tree

I'm trying to write a recursive function for an arbitrary binary tree that takes a value and a leaf node and it checks to see if a leaf node has that value. This is roughly what I have right now.

```
bool tree_eq(value, N* node){
  if (node == nullptr){
    return false;
    }
  else{
    if node->value == value{
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return tree_eq(value, N->left);
      return tree_eq(value, N->right);
    }
```

I know I can't return two things and that is the part I'm struggling to solve. How do I recursively check the right side and the left side if given a root and not a leaf? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know if the node is either in the left side or the right side (doesn't really matter the side), so you can say :

```
 ...
 else {
    return (tree_eq(value,N->left) || tree_eq(value,N->right) );
 }
```

These will lead to a depth first search where always the left most branch of nodes is taken into consideration.

Comment: what if the given node is a root, so I HAVE TO go left and right?

Comment: You will always go both left and right until you find a value. However if something returns true, everything works fine .

Comment: I don't see how the || makes sure that both sides are checked. If I start at the root, and its 2 leaves does not == the value, it would randomly check the right or the left, but not both. That's what I'm getting from the ||

Comment: You will check the left side and if that side is negative (nothing found) you will check the right side. Isn't this what you want ?

Comment: Think I got it now. I got mixed up with return(...) || return(...). Thank you

Comment: @MichaelCMS - Won't the '||' clause short-circuit (and not do the right branch) if the value is found in the left?

Comment: @DOUGLAS yes, it will . But from my understanding OP doesn't want this (And you shouldn't want this , otherwise you could just keep everything in a vector). You can avoid short-circuits by keeping the boolean results and returing (result1 || result2) . However, going in the right branch won't have any effect on the result.

Answer (score 2):

When your tree is unsorted, change your ending else clause from

```
 return tree_eq(value, N->left);
 return tree_eq(value, N->right);
```

and try to 'Or' these two results, as in

```
 return (tree_eq(value, N->left) ||
         tree_eq(value, N->right));
```

If your tree is sorted, you need only dfs down one side or the other, not both.

Note that the '||' will not invoke the right branch if found in left branch.